# java data structure to replace file io

Tags: java, file, data-structures, jsoup

My program goes to a my uni results page, finds all the links and saves to a file. Then I read the file and copy only lines which contain required links and save it to another file. Then I parse it again to extract required data

```
public class net {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jntuconnect.net/results_archive/").get();

        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        File f1 = new File("flink.txt");
        File f2 = new File("rlink.txt");

            //write extracted links to f1 file
        FileUtils.writeLines(f1, links);

            // store each link from f1 file in string list
        List<String>  linklist  = FileUtils.readLines(f1);

            // second string list to store only required link elements
        List<String> rlinklist = new ArrayList<String>();

        // loop which finds required links and stores in rlinklist 
        for(String elem : linklist){
            if(elem.contains("B.Tech") && (elem.contains("R07")||elem.contains("R09"))){
                rlinklist.add(elem);                
            }           
        }           
        //store required links in f2 file
        FileUtils.writeLines(f2, rlinklist);

        // parse links from f2  file
        Document rdoc = Jsoup.parse(f2, null);
        Elements rlinks = rdoc.select("a");

        //  for storing hrefs and link text 
        List<String> rhref = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> rtext = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(Element rlink : rlinks){
            rhref.add(rlink.attr("href"));
            rtext.add(rlink.text());
        }

    }// end main

}
```

I don't want to create files to do this. Is there a better way to get hrefs and link texts of only specific urls without creating files?

It uses Apache commons fileutils, jsoup

Comment: You already have the list in memory (`Elements links`). Just operate on that. Your code to write and read from files is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get rid of the first file write/read:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a");
List<String> linklist = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element elt : links) {
    linklist.add(elt.toString());
}
```

The second round trip, if I understand the code, is intended to extract the links that meet a certain test. You can just do that in memory using the same technique.

I see you're relying on `Jsoup.parse` to extract the href and link text from the selected links. You can do that in memory by writing the selected nodes to a `StringBuffer`, convert it to a `String` by calling it's `toString()` method, and then using one of the `Jsoup.parse` methods that takes a `String` instead of a `File` argument.